# Load testing tool that can send PUT/DELETE methods

Tags: testing, rest, load-testing

I am finding load testing tool that can send PUT/DELETE requests.
Neither ApacheBench nor JMeter supports these methods.

After several hours' googling, I found [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) that looks good.

Do you have any other recommendation?
Command line tool like ApacheBench will be better for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) is a decent load testing framework that also supports PUT and DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter supports put and delete methods as of of versions > to 2.5 ( didn't Check for others)